# Translation English->Chinese for computer words

Tags: translation, simplified-characters

I would like to get the translation of the following words into Chinese Simplified. All those words belong to the world of computer. Basically, I want to get the same words as you would see in the UI of major software (Firefox/Windows10/...)

Think that you would have a button for each word below. What would you read in a Chinese software interface?

copy, cut, paste, cancel, about... are good examples of words that you will see in every software UI and have a special meaning that an automated translator won't understand well. For instance, Google translate doesn't seem to do a good job.

```
Abort
About
Advanced
Apply
Back
Bluetooth
Cancel
Copy
CPU
Cut
Delete
Device
Downgrade
Format microSD
Hardware
Internet
MicroSD
Next
No
OK
Options
Paste
Play
Processor
Server
Settings
Size
Software
Sound
Storage
Upgrade
Video
Web
Wi-Fi
Yes
```

It would be better to have someone who is using a Chinese computer to answer that question.

Comment: Google translate can do very good job about this kind of words.
https://translate.google.com/

Comment: Have you even read my question?!?  This is exactly where Google Translate can completely fail: for instance because there is little context when there is only one word to translate (try to Google translate for back == 返回)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you didn't do enough research... anyway it is just a simple question for me.

I guess you just set the system language to Chinese and it is solved.

Abort 中止

About 关于

Advanced 高级

Apply 应用

Back 返回

Bluetooth 蓝牙

Cancel 取消

Copy 复制

CPU CPU/中央处理单元

Cut 剪切

Delete 删除

Device 设备

Downgrade 降级

Format 样式

microSD microSD

Hardware 硬件

Internet 因特网/互联网

Next 下一项/次项

No 否

OK 是

Options 选项

Paste 粘贴

Play 播放

Processor 处理器

Server 服务器

Settings 设置

Size 尺寸

Software 软件

Sound 声音

Storage 存储

Upgrade 升级

Video 视频

Web 网络

Wi-Fi WIFI

Yes 是

Comment: You should add newlines in that list so its easier to read. I think this is a good question because it would be good to have such a list all in one place. I might make myself some flash cards based on these.